# Change where pip path (or pip)

Tags: python

So I have 2 different versions of python installed, one via Anaconda 3 and one via Homebrew for VSC. Now I would like to install a new package with pip3 install pandas (for example), but the it tells me I have installed said package already.
Which is true, since my Anaconda 3 installation uses said package.

If I type:

```
Which pip 
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip 
Which pip3 
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip3 
Which python 
/opt/anaconda3/bin/python
```

What I take from this, is that I am trying to install in the wrong "folder"? It should be:
`/usr/local/bin/python3`

I read on stack overflow that one can use "-t" or "--target", others said this is wrong... So I just wanna change to the pip that's installed under /usr/local/bin.
(Sorry I am a bit new to this, so still learning...)

Comment: "Don't", at least not like this. Except for pip itself, don't install packages globally, [create virtual environments](https://realpython.com/python-virtual-environments-a-primer/) and then run your pip install commands after activating whatever virtual environment you need to be working in.

Comment: (And note that conda [has its own commands for this](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html), so whether you want to use python or conda is up to you, but always use virtual environments)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So I checked with a friend what virtual environments are, main problem it's not what I am looking for. For me, someone who just uses libraries which are never changing (apart from performance increases, numpy, pandas, matplotlib and so on), will never change where I will need a certain version. It just seems like more of a pain, and less real use for me. 
Plus my idea is also to learn how I can change it, because I think that changing this directory shouldn't be too hard, and it seems like something important...

Comment: It's literally trivial to use, and gets you in the right habit. Just use virtual environments. Calling "telling conda to activate your venv with a single command" a pain is _kind of_ ridiculous =) As for changing dirs, not hard, you just run the venv command again in the new dir, then you copy over the venv's `Lib` dir, instead of copying the entire venv. So, barely an inconvenience.

Comment: As stated before, a virtual environment is as far as I know (and understand) for every folder separate, installing 15 different libraries which I would like to use in my 5 different folders seems to be more of a pain than anything. Again, I don't see any advantage or need to use a virtual environment. 
Your solution solves my problem in the VENV, which I don't use, I have found a way of using an alias, but this isn't permanent, it's an alias. 
So I think I might set everything up again, or delete anaconda if there is no proper way of doing it globally... :(

Comment: Except in regular Python dev, you absolutely want separate dependency dirs, because different dirs/projects may need different versions of _the same_ library or even different versions of Python. So getting in the habit of using venvs means you're also able to run _other_ people's code, as well as have other people look at _your_ code, without global versioning conflicts. So by all means, don't use them, but then versioning conflicts (including _the one in this post_) really are a problem of your own making. It's literally the problem that venvs were _designed_ to solve =)

Comment: Ah, ok yeah if that's the case then it absolutely makes sense, you know for someone who just does basic data analysis (I couldn't even imagine why something works in one version in another it won't, never wrote huge codes). (Also have a lot of stuff to do, since when you study physics programming is not your main concern... You just need stuff to work).
Anyway, thank you for your answer, I will add a post down below explaining my fix, and then close it :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I will try and summarise it shortly:
The problem, as stated above by Mike (Thank you Mike), can be solved with VENV. This is a bit of a more complicated approach, but it would be the proper approach (so see above if that's your goal).

You don't want the longer approach since you're like me and use python for data analysis? I got you homie:

```
% which pip
/opt/anaconda3/bin/pip
% alias pip=/usr/local/bin/pip
% which pip
pip: aliased to /usr/local/bin/pip
```

Now you do this for pip, pip3, python and whatever else you need.
After that you can do:

```
pip install pandas
```

Or whatever other package you need apart from pandas. Not sure how this alias works because after doing other stuff it disappeared, SO THIS IS NOT A PERMANENT FIX, sadly.
There is a way of creating an alias document which you can load in once, but I have no clue how that works.

Hope this helped :D